# Solve returns format I don't understand with dollar sign ($)

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have the following function

```
K[theta_, phi_] := Module[{c1, c2, c3, Phi, PhiPr, x, y},
  {c1, c2, c3} = 
   1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3};
  Phi = Sqrt[((c2 + c3)^2 - c1^2)/(4 c2 c3)];
  PhiPr = ((c3 - c2)/c1) Phi;
  If[0 <= Phi^2 <= 1,
   {x, y} /. 
    Solve[Sin[Sqrt[3] x/2] == Phi && 
      Sin[3 y/2] == 
       PhiPr && (c2 + c3) Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] == -c1 Cos[3 y/2] && -Pi <=
        x <= Pi && -Pi <= y <= Pi, {x, y}]
   , Null]
  ]
```

Sometimes it behaves itself and returns me either a Null (as desired) or an actual number. However sometimes it is a naughty function and returns something strange. For example if I compute `K[0.1,0]` it returns me `{x$17889, y$17889}`.

What is this output? I don't understand. Many thanks

Comment: When Solve cannot find a solution it returns {}. {x,y}/.{} is just {x,y}. But inside any module all the variable names are aliased with a $ and a claimed unique serial number. So that is what you are seeing, the aliased local variables from your Module. You could verify all this with a carefully positioned Print statement.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/module-and-local-variable.  Perhaps there's a better candidate for a duplicate, but this is basically how `Module` works and is explained in the "Details" section of its documentation page.

Comment: Ah.. I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the problem by performing the steps in your function one at a time for `theta = .1` and `phi = 0.`.

```
{c1, c2, c3} = 1 - 3 Sin[0.1]^2 Cos[0 - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3}
{* {0.9701, 0.992525, 0.992525} *}

Phi = Sqrt[((c2 + c3)^2 - c1^2)/(4 c2 c3)]
{* 0.87245 *}

PhiPr = ((c3 - c2)/c1) Phi
{* 0. *}
```

Because `0 <= Phi^2 <= 1` is `True`, the `Solve` is executed:

```
{x, y} /. Solve[Sin[Sqrt[3] x/2] == Phi && Sin[3 y/2] == 
    PhiPr && (c2 + c3) Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] == -c1 Cos[3 y/2] && -Pi <= x <= Pi && -Pi <= y <= Pi, 
    {x, y}]
```

returning the error message `Solve::ratnz` and `{x, y}` instead of an answer.  Returning now to your original function, a `Module`, `x` and `y` are temporary variables, which have names beginning with `$`, which is what you are getting.

**Addendum**

Replace the `If` statement in the `Module` by

```
If[0 <= Phi^2 <= 1, Check[{x, y} /. Solve[Sin[Sqrt[3] x/2] == Phi && 
  Sin[3 y/2] == PhiPr && (c2 + c3) Cos[Sqrt[3] x/2] == -c1 Cos[3 y/2] && -Pi <= x <= Pi &&
  -Pi <= y <= Pi, {x, y}], Null], Null]]
```

to obtain a `Null` response is such cases.