# Dropping \$NUMBER from local var$number when passing results from a Module

Tags: scoping, localization

I'm sure this has been asked, but I can't seem to find the correct terms to find it.

I have a function that looks something like this

```
myFunction[data_]:=Module[{result, x, y}, 
      result = NMinimize[ myModel[data, x, y], {x, y}];
      Return[result]
]
```

When I use it my results look something like

```
{1234, x$2319->10, y$2319 -> 0.023}
```

Besides working with global variables, how do I remove the `$2319` from `x$2319` and `y$2319` (ideally as part of `myFunction`) so I can use the results more easily?

Comment: Don't localize `x` and `y` with the `$Module`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Note the phrase "Besides working with global funcdtions..." (which should read "Besides working with global variables")

Comment: This is what [contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) are built for. One can strip the numbers via `SymbolName` and `ToExpression`, but that's hacky and not likely to be a solid solution long term.

Comment: Not the same problem but related by solution: [114769](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this is to pass in symbols from caller that you want to be part of returned expression.

```
myFunction[data_,x_,y_]:=Module[{result},
result={data,x,y}
];

ClearAll[x,y]
myFunction[{1,2,3},x,y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No dollars any more. This is how Mathematica does it. For example, `NDSolve` and `DSolve` etc... they take in `y[x]` and also `x` from user scope so that the result returned will not have $$ in it.

See [module-and-local-variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/module-and-local-variable) also

Answer (score 0):

The solution I like best is to replace Module[] with Block[].  Simple and given in [Module and Local variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/module-and-local-variable) as pointed out by Nasser (thanks!).

Comment: Check what happens if `x` and `y` have global values before you call this function.  Wanting to localize and wanting to return `x` and `y` from the function are kind of contradictory.