# Avoid context mark in Plot labels in package

Tags: plotting, front-end, notebooks, packages, contexts

Minimal example:

```
BeginPackage["plots`"]
s::usage = "s[max] plots ..."
x
y
Begin["`Private`"]
s[max_] := 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, max}, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm@x, HoldForm@y}]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

After executing `s[...]` labels are `x` and `y`. But if I have (before or after package loading) some definitions for `x` and `y` I will get warnings abot multiple contexts and shadowing.

I can remove `x` and `y` from exporting part of package, but then I get `` plots`Private`x `` and similar for axes labels.

I used to set labels with `HoldForm@x` to avoid possible definitions for `x` and to have usual `TraditionalForm` for label.

How to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not using string?

Comment: @xzczd, please elaborate. How to combine string and TraditionalForm?

Comment: You mean you need it be italic? Then `Style["x", Italic]`. You can also select the symbol in string and press Ctrl+i.

Comment: @xzczd, plrobably this is a way to go. But I mean, in a notebook I use `Axeslabel ->{HoldForm@x,HoldForm@y}` and get nicely formatted labels. Can this be done with packages and all this "nightmare" of contexts?

Comment: @xzczd, I tried your suggestion with `Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(y\)]\)", Italic]` and `HoldForm[Subscript[\[Beta], y]]`, they look different, `\[Beta]` e.g.

Comment: 1. If you insist on the `HoldForm` approach, one possible workaround is ``Internal`$ContextMarks = False`` 2. For the `\[Beta]` case you don't need the `Italic` style.

Comment: @xzczd, OK, your first suggestion ``Internal`$ContextMarks = False`` works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer. If you insist on the `HoldForm` approach, setting

```
Internal`$ContextMarks = False;
```

is a possible workaround. If you don't want to set `` Internal`$ContextMarks `` globally, modify `s` to the following:

```
…
s3[max_] := 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, max}, 
  AxesLabel -> 
   Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False}, 
    ToExpression@MakeBoxes@{HoldForm@x, HoldForm@y}]]
…
```

If you have many functions to be fixed in the package, define a helper function for the task:

```
BeginPackage["plots`"]
s::usage = "s[max] plots ..."
s2
Begin["`Private`"]

nomark = Function[expr, 
   Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False}, ToExpression@MakeBoxes@expr], HoldAll];

s[max_] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, max}, AxesLabel -> nomark@{HoldForm@x, HoldForm@y}]
s2[max_] := Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, max}, AxesLabel -> nomark@{HoldForm@x, HoldForm@y}]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Comment: Is it safe to put this ``Internal`$ContextMarks = False`` command in `init.m`? And why we need `ToExpression` / `MakeBoxes` staff?

Comment: @LittleCat1 Setting it globally to `False` can cause trouble in certain case, see the end of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162834/1871 . ``Internal`$ContextMarks`` actually effects in `MakeBoxes` stage, so `Block` is not enough. Try e.g. ``Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False}, a`b]``. Also, observe the output of ``Global`b = 123; Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False}, 
 a`b // MakeBoxes // ToExpression]`` to understand how it works.

Comment: OK, I see. So I will stick with a helper function to strip context marks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is to pass $x$ and $y$ symbols in the call itself. This is what Mathematica does. See [module-and-local-variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/module-and-local-variable)

### First option

So your package will becomes

```
Quit[]

BeginPackage["plots`"]
s::usage="s[max] plots ..."
Begin["`Private`"]
s[max_,x_,y_]:=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,max},AxesLabel->{x,y}]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

And now

```
s[10,x,y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Second option

Option 1 is what I would do.

But if you do not want to pass the symbols to use, another option is to have a private function in your package, called `strip` which you call it on any local module symbol that you want to return back to the caller. This function basically knowns you package name and will strip away the leading package indicator from any symbol. So your package becomes

```
Quit[]
x=10; (*does not affect anything now*)

BeginPackage["plots`"]
s::usage="s[max] plots ..."
Begin["`Private`"]

(*private stipping function*)
strip[expr_]:=Module[{},
   StringReplace[ToString[expr,FormatType->TraditionalForm],"plots`Private`"~~c:LetterCharacter~~"$"~~DigitCharacter..:>c]
]

(*even though x,y here are local to this module *)
(*when returning, they will NOT have any $ or package indicators*)

s[max_]:=Module[{x,y},
   Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,max},AxesLabel->{strip@x,strip@y}]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

and now

```
s[10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For completion, will add option suggested by xzczd in comment. But for this, the symbols $x,y$ have to be package wide visible. I prefer myself not to have this, as they become global to the whole package.

### Third option

```
Quit[]
x=10;

BeginPackage["plots`"]
s::usage="s[max] plots ..."
Begin["`Private`"]
Internal`$ContextMarks=False; (*this strips package name*)
(*notice, now x,y are global to the package (but private to world) *)
x 
y
s[max_]:=Module[{},
  Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,max},AxesLabel->{x,y}]]

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

And now

```
s[10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]